# What is the significance of annoying phone ring?

Tags: once-upon-a-time-in-america

What is the significance of annoying phone ring in *Once Upon a Time in America*?

At the the beginning of the movie, the phone rang for 4 to 5 minutes continuously.

Comment: It may help to italicize the title of the movie and spell it out correctly. Also, putting the title of the movie in your question's title may help as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The annoying phone ring in the **Once Upon a Time in America** scene you quoted, is there not for the purpose of annoying the viewer (which I admit id does a bit), but is there to share with the viewer and impress in the audience the feeling experienced by Noodles (De Niro).

In order to reach the desidered effect, **it has** to be long and certainly not pleasant.

The phone ring is not real, it's just in Noodles head and expresses the metaphorical ring of his guilty conscience, which is stirred in the opium den by the newspaper's headlines hovering over the photos of Max, Patsy and Cockeye that read *"Bootleggers trapped by Feds; Three Slain"*. Noodles tries once again to obliterate the painful memory of his betrayal triggered by the newspaper by sucking greedily on the opium pipe, bu to no avail.

The scene is also beautifully edited in reverse, thus the audience does really understand the meaning of the ringing phone only at the end of the sequence, when we see Noodles picking up the phone and calling the desk of Sergeant Halloran (we are only shown the nametag on his desk). When Halloran (or one of his agents) picks up, the ringing stops and is replaced by a deafening, high-pitched noise that forces Noodles to stand up, no matter the amount of opium smoked.

Here's the *phone ring* scene from Youtube:

Comment: Screw that, it is annoying as f***. I skipped it. Leone needs to convey his message without infuriating his audience.

Comment: agree with @nicolasMiari An artist can convey meaning without beating us over the head with their intention